# WebDriver - invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, codeception

I'm trying to reuse a login session with `$I->saveSessionSnapshot($session_name)` and `$I->loadSessionSnapshot($session_name)`, but I get the following error on the second test:

```
  [Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnrecognizedExceptionException] invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b33893869b8c1339e8f4d9ed1816f143-refs/branch-heads/3945@{#614}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

The issue is that the saved `PHPSESSID` cookie has `null` as the `expiry`, where an integer is expected.

Is this an issue in WebDriver or Codeception? How can I get past it?

As a workaround I have changed the following code in `vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Cookie.php` from:

```php
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
      return $this->cookie;
    }
```

to:

```php
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
      $cookie = $this->cookie;
      if ($cookie['expiry'] === null) {
        unset($cookie['expiry']);
      }
      return $cookie;
    }
```

Obviously changing vendor source files is a bad idea, so what's the approved way of solving this problem?

Comment: You have a mismatch between Chrome and ChromeDriver versions. You can find the correct version in https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: @Guy Yes I did, but that wasn't the issue.